# iOS - Table View Cell with UITextView not resizing properly

Tags: ios, textview, height, tableview, cell

I have subclassed a cell class and am using prototypes from Storyboard. The cell in question has an embedded textview that will display varying lengths of text.
I already setup the cell height in *heightForRowAtIndexPath:*, but trying to resize the textview itself in *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* does not work properly.
It wont resize on initial load, but will once I scroll the cell out of view then back in. But if I keep scrolling back and forth, it occasionaly shrinks back down again.

Code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int defaultSize = 0;
    int height = 0;
    if(indexPath.section%2==0){
        defaultSize = 160;
        NSMutableDictionary *currentPost = [newsFeedPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSString *string = [currentPost valueForKey:@"detailsText"];
        CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        height = stringSize.height + defaultSize;
        NSLog(@"String Size Before: %f",stringSize.height);

    }else{
        defaultSize = 270;
        height = defaultSize;
    }
    return height;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;
    if(indexPath.section%2==0){
        CellIdentifier = @"NewsFeedText";
    }else{
        CellIdentifier = @"NewsFeedImage";
    }
    NewsFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell setBackgroundView:[[NewsFeedCellBackground alloc] init]];
    [cell.bottomContainer setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [cell.bottomContainer.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.imagePreview.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [cell.bottomContainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height-30, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 30)];

    //Data Object
    NSMutableDictionary *currentPost = [newsFeedPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    //View
    cell.userImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[currentPost valueForKey:@"userImage"]];
    cell.userName.text = [currentPost valueForKey:@"userName"];
    cell.createdDate.text = [currentPost valueForKey:@"createdDate"];
    cell.patientName.text = [currentPost valueForKey:@"patientName"];
    cell.detailsText.text = [currentPost valueForKey:@"detailsText"];
    [cell.imagePreview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[currentPost valueForKey:@"imagePreview"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.viewCase addTarget:self action:@selector(displayCase:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Image
    [cell.imagePreview addTarget:self action:@selector(displayImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Data
    cell.viewCase.tag = [[currentPost valueForKey:@"caseID"] intValue];

    //Cell Adjustments
    NSString *string = [currentPost valueForKey:@"detailsText"];
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"String Size After: %f",stringSize.height);
    [cell.detailsText setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.detailsText.frame.origin.x, cell.detailsText.frame.origin.y, cell.detailsText.frame.size.width, stringSize.height+10)];
    [cell.detailsText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: This would be much easier to do by adding the text view in the storyboard and giving it the right constraints. It will grow automatically with the cell, so you only need to calculate the cell height.

Comment: Yes I am using autoLayout. Still a bit new to using it though. What would be the appropriate constraints? The cell is basically identical to a Facebook News Feed cell (user image/name at top, textview in middle, link banner view on bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out using auto layout allowed me to just set the Top space and Bottom space to the superview (cell view), and since the cell height is changed in *heightForRowAtIndexPath:* the textview then gets resized automagically.

Comment: This just helped me fix my exact issue! Many thanks!